# Firefox ignores @font-face generated by FontSquirrel

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I have generated a @font-face with FontSquirrel, and resulted these (tweaked later) rules:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CabinSketchRoBold';
    src: url('cabinsketchro-boldwebfont.eot');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'CabinSketchRoBold';
    src: url('cabinsketchro-boldwebfont.woff') format('woff'),
         local('?'), url('cabinsketchro-boldwebfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('cabinsketchro-boldwebfont.svg#CabinSketchRoBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Style is applied in the css file like this:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-weight:normal;font-family:'CabinSketchRoBold',Arial,sans-serif !important; }
```

Everithing works fine in Chrome, even in InternetExplorer, but in **newer** versions of Firefox, the font doesn't load. It loads in FF 3.6... o_O

I have another font, Ubuntu, loaded from Google via the JavaScript option, and that one loads ok, even on the headings, after changing

```
font-family:'CabinSketchRoBold','Ubuntu',Arial,sans-serif !important;
```

What's wrong with the declarations that makes FF ignore my local font?

EDIT: this is not only on localhost, it happens on the live site too. I have looked at other answers and tried them out, but no luck. WOFF was even base64 encoded, same result.

**SOLVED: Seems that the .eot being in a separate declaration (again, FontSquirrel generated) was doing the damage. Moving it with the others solved it. Thanks Boris Zbarsky!**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CabinSketchRoBold';
    src: url('cabinsketchro-boldwebfont.eot?#') format('eot'),
         url('cabinsketchro-boldwebfont.woff') format('woff'),
         local('?'), url('cabinsketchro-boldwebfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('cabinsketchro-boldwebfont.svg#CabinSketchRoBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: You should provide generated CSS code, not LESS source code.

Comment: I updated the question with the CSS part.

Comment: Not sure what that local tagg is doing there, with the question mark. Are you running this local or on a webserver. I do would suggest not keeping it in the root. I would try to keep my root folder clean with just a mere files. Your last url with the # in it, doesn

Comment: Do you see any errors reported in the error console?  Is there a link to a live site that shows the problem?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky - no error, everything works fine except for one font in FF. Live site here: [hackathon.ro](http://www.hackathon.ro)

Comment: @Dorvalla that local thing is a possible hack, discovered by [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/#smiley)

Comment: @MariusStuparu No error?  On the live site you linked to, I'm seeing the following errors reported: `[03:32:41.012] downloadable font: invalid version tag (font-family: "CabinSketchRoBold" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0)
source: http://www.hackathon.ro/wp-content/themes/hackathon/css/fonts/cabinsketchro-boldwebfont.eot @ http://www.hackathon.ro/wp-content/themes/hackathon/css/fonts/cabinsketch.css`

Comment: @MariusStuparu and `Timestamp: 10/11/12 3:34:04 AM
Error: downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "CabinSketchRoBold" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0)
source: http://www.hackathon.ro/wp-content/themes/hackathon/css/fonts/cabinsketchro-boldwebfont.eot
Source File: http://www.hackathon.ro/wp-content/themes/hackathon/css/fonts/cabinsketch.css
Line: 0
Source Code:
@font-face {   font-family: "CabinSketchRoBold";   src: url("cabinsketchro-boldwebfont.eot"); }`

Comment: And in particular, if I remove that eot rule, things suddenly work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are actually defining two separate faces of the "CabinSketchRoBold" font.

The first face is normal weight and uses .eot file for the font data.

The second face is bold weight and uses one of woff, truetype, svg, whichever is available.

Then you're styling text that's normal weight.  So the first face is picked.  See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-fonts/#font-style-matching for the spec on this.

In particular, following the steps in that spec, in step 4 we end up a single face: the .eot one.  But since the browser can't do anything with that font format, this face has no glyphs so in step 5 the browser moves on to the next family name.  The other (bold) face in the "CabinSketchRoBold" family is not considered, per spec.

So the upshot is that you should either list `font-weight: bold` in both your rules or in neither one.  Then the .eot and the other options would all be considered as sources for a single font face, not for different faces in the same family.

It looks like Chrome doesn't actually follow the spec here, unfortunately...

Comment: Hm. That's odd, because so does Opera and Internet Explorer and Safari... The definitions were generated by FontSquirrel, so I asumed they were good. Let me try to fix and I'll come back.

Comment: It's possible that they still implement an earlier draft of the spec.  Aa far as as FontSquirrel goes, it's not perfect, unfortunately.  :(

Answer (score 2):

The latest versions of Firefox are able to show the font related errors in the tools->web developer->errors console. for example this is the error I give with a custom font:

```
Error: downloadable font: table 'GSUB': OpenType layout data discarded
```

Comment: Thanks, did'n know about that, but still no font-related error (only some selector warnings) and still no font...

Answer (score 1):

You must have this font type for working in IE,Firefox,Chrome

```
    @font-face
{
    font-family: 'BHoma';
    src: url('/public/font/BHoma.eot?#')format('eot'), 
    url('/public/font/BHoma.ttf')format('truetype'),
    url('/public/font/BHoma.woff')format('woff'), 
    url('/public/font/BHoma.svg#BHoma')format('svg');
}
```

but you first must generate your font from this link

http://www.codeandmore.com/2011/06/font-face-kit-generator/

Comment: What's different in your declaration from mine? They're exactly the same, but with better protection for MSIE and cross-origin restrictions (mine). It was generated by FontSquirrel.